# sem_wait unable to continue

Tags: c, concurrency, ipc, multiprocessing, semaphore

I have a process spawning off a few child processes. They are all sharing one semaphore.

In my main program.

```
sem_t *sharedSem = sem_open(SHAREDSEM, O_CREAT, 0600, 4); // Initial 1
```

In my child program.

```
> sem_t * serverSem = sem_open(SHAREDSEM, 0);     
sem_wait(serverSem); 
printf("PRINTING\n");  
sem_post(sharedSem);
```

My observation is that the problem lies within sem_wait. Anything that happens before sem_wait on the child process will print out fine. However, the printf() after sem_wait will never print. Not even once.

I've been at it for a few hours and I can't see my problem. Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Is the semaphore being initialised (sem_init)? The sem_wait() call is blocking because the semaphore value is zero.

Comment: If I remove the sem_wait, anything after sem_post won't print either. It seems like any sem_ functions will block.

Comment: Have you checked that the sem_open() call is successful?

Comment: @suspectus: `sem_init` and `sem_open` are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that behavior is caused by a missing sem_close() for the previous runnings.
Just assure that you correctly close the semaphore so that in future runs the starting value of the semaphore is correctly assigned and the sem_wait() should work.